# Convert a 3D model from Blender to .obj

Tags: 3d, blendergis

I have created a 3D Model in Blender by using a DEM and displacement modifier.
I know how to render and get an image, but my question is how I can export it as a .obj so that can be embedded in websites for example?
I have tried with file-> save as -> .obj but I get the plane without any "displacement" or 3D perspective

Comment: How are you trying to embed the obj file? Which framework are you using?

Comment: not using any until now.. I am trying via https://3dviewer.net/